# how to take list as input in single line python

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, input

how to take list as a input in python in a single line.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/275aY.png)I tried following  thing but it didn't worked

Comment: Don't make us retype code from an image to reproduce your problem.  Please post all code and error messages as plain text.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask], [mre] and the other links found on those pages. [Why should I not upload images of ... when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Time to read a tutorial? What I mean is that you should not try to invent a syntax that looks nice for what you want, but instead find in tutos examples close to what you want, run them with no change to make sure you did not add typos, and then modify them to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take input separated by space:

```
input_string = input("Enter a list element separated by space ")
lst  = input_string.split()
```

You can also take input separated by any other character as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by accepting the numbers on a single line separated by spaces and then split it to get all the numbers as a list, then map it to an integer value to produce the required integer list.

```
numList = list(map(int, input("Enter a list of numbers separated by spaces: ").split()))
print(numList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [eval](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval) function.

```
_list = eval(input("enter the list:"))
```

When prompted you pass the list as follow: `[1, 2, 3]`

Your `_list` variable will be a list structure containing 1, 2 and 3 as elements.

Edit: this, of course, does not guarantee that only lists will be accepted on the input, so have this in mind.

Answer (score -1):

```
list1 = input("data with spaces: ").split(" ")
list2 = input("data with commas: ")split(",")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.